# Firebase/angularFire - Should I still use $add when using 3 way data binding?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have the following code in an Angular app that uses AngularFire/Firebase:

```
FirebaseBooks.$bind($scope, "books");
```

Firebase books being a service returning me a firebase object

Then to add a new book I would normally (before setting up 3 way data binding) do

```
$scope.books.$add({
    name: $scope.bookName,
    isbn: $scope.bookIsbn,
    thumbnail: $scope.bookThumbnail,
    publishedDate: $scope.bookPublishedDate,
    description: $scope.bookDescription
  })
```

Is this still the best way now I'm wanting to use 3 way binding or should I use some other method, the docs seem to suggest I no longer need $add? If I don't what should I use to get the above into $scope.books in a firebase friendly way?

Forgive me if this is a stupid question!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add items directly into the bound object and they will be sent to the server. To obtain a unique, chronological ID, you could still use $add, or you could obtain one directly from Firebase, too:

```
var ref = new Firebase(URL);
var data = $firebase(ref);
data.$bind( $scope, 'books' );

$scope.addToBooks = function(title) {
   var uniqueId = ref.push().name();
   $scope.books[uniqueId] = title;
};
```

Comment: Thanks once again for your firebase help :)

Comment: Sorry quick follow up - my factory looks like this:

.factory('FirebaseBooks', ['$firebase', function($firebase) {
  return $firebase(new Firebase("https://xxxx.firebaseIO.com/books"));
}])

How can I call .push().name(); as FirebaseBooks.push().name(); fails. Should I just use $add when I'm using the factory? I didn't want to do  new Firebase(URL); outside of the factory.

Comment: .push() is on the Firebase ref, not $firebase. Note that I assigned `var ref = new Firebase()` and then did `ref.push().name()`; this is all covered in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that binding is not mandatory.

**Using :**

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.6/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.7.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

You could do :

```
app.factory('FirebaseBooks', ['$firebase', function($firebase) 
{ 
    var firebase_base_url = "xxxx.firebaseIO.com/books";

    return {
            getBookRef: function(bookID,childName)
            {
                fb_url = firebase_base_url+'/'+bookID;
                var firebaseRef = new Firebase(fb_url);
                return $firebase(firebaseRef);
            }
        };
}]);
```

and then :

```
$scope.bookRef = firebaseService.getBookRef(bookID); // MAY OR MAY NOT BE ALREADY POPULATED 

    $scope.bookRef.$on('loaded', function(snapshot) 
    {
        // IF FIREBASE REF IS EMPTY, POPULATE IT
        if(snapshot === null) 
        {
            $scope.bookRef.$set(
                {
                   name: $scope.bookName,
                   isbn: $scope.bookIsbn,
                   thumbnail: $scope.bookThumbnail,
                   publishedDate: $scope.bookPublishedDate,
                   description: $scope.bookDescription
                }).then(function(ref) 
            {
                // DO WHAT THOU WILST WITH YOUR PROMISE BEING FULFILLED
            });
        } 
        // --- EOF - IF FIREBASE REF IS EMPTY, POPULATE IT
        else 
        {
            // console.log('snapshot seems to be already populated');
        }
        console.log('---> snapshot : ');
        console.log(snapshot);
    });
```

Once $scope.*firebaseRef* is 3-way binded, you can just manipulate the $scope.*firebaseRef*, which is a JS object, in your controller's functions, and then just use .$save(). 
You may have a function that deletes a child entry using $child(), for example. 
Let's say you bind this 'addAuthorfromUI' function to a submit button in your UI :

```
$scope.addAuthorfromUI = function(bookID) // ASSUMING NG-MODEL 'bookID' IS PASSED
    {
     $scope.bookRef.author = $scope.author; // ASSUMING NG-MODEL 'author' IN TEMPLATE
     $scope.bookRef.$save(); // YOU JUST APPENDED STUFF TO THE OBJECT, NOW SAVE IT TO FB
     }
```

Not sure why $bind() is not needed, it may be because of the versions I use, this is why I specified the APIs versions.

Comment: In your first example, you pass but don't use childName - what did you intend to do with that? Thanks for the in-depth answer too!

Comment: Whoops, my bad, forgot to delete it. Don't take it into account. In my system, the "getBookRef" is a multi-purpose function. In my original code, if childName is provided, then the FireBase JS Object returned is... a child. It's a modular approach : instead of multiplying services (factories), you only have one, and you pass the name of the object you want to retrieve. So in this case "getBookRef" would be "getObjectRef", and the factory function could accept (ObjectName,ObjectID,[childName]). And so :
var book = getObjectRef("book",$id);
var book_s_author = getObjectRef("book",$id, "author");